# Set/change lock_monitor default interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have read this documentation on technet : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx

In my application, I have to respond to an industrial machine within 5 seconds. Sometimes (appromimatively once a day), I encounter deadlock in database, and re-run the transaction. This procedure works well.

My problem is the deadlock resolution duration. Knowing that I have 5 seconds available to respond to the machine, I would like to set the default interval for lock_monitor thread to 2 seconds. Therefore a deadlock could be detected and resolved in 5 seconds, because now, it take up to 7 seconds to resolve it.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you figure this out stephane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the blocked process threshold, but you shouldn't.

[Configure Blocked Threshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181150.aspx)

[Increase / Decrease Threshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402879.aspx)

[Why You Shouldn't Do This...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2157154)

Side note...

> If the lock monitor thread finds deadlocks, the deadlock detection interval will drop from 5 seconds to as low as 100 milliseconds depending on the frequency of deadlocks.
>
> If the lock monitor thread stops finding deadlocks, the Database
>   Engine increases the intervals between searches to 5 seconds.
>
> If a deadlock has just been detected, it is assumed that the next
>   threads that must wait for a lock are entering the deadlock cycle. The
>   first couple of lock waits after a deadlock has been detected will
>   immediately trigger a deadlock search rather than wait for the next
>   deadlock detection interval. For example, if the current interval is 5
>   seconds, and a deadlock was just detected, the next lock wait will
>   kick off the deadlock detector immediately. If this lock wait is part
>   of a deadlock, it will be detected right away rather than during next deadlock search

[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/187359dc-ec5e-41f1-ac67-16fdb3c3fbf7/is-it-possible-to-change-deadlock-detection-interval-time-to-less-than-5-seconds?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: It's strange ! I don't understand if it is a bug or a voluntary feature. Why does [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2157154) say : _The minimum time it can detect a blocked process is 5 seconds_ ? It is not fully configurable ?

Comment: Not a bug @stephanejulien